# Espresso: RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition doesn't work

Tags: android, android-espresso

I started testing my app with Espresso.
My app have a recyclerView.
Below code works:

```
int position = 0;
        onView(TestUtils.withIndex(withId(R.id.recyclerViewIcons),0)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(position,ViewActions.click()));
```

But below code doesn't work

```
int position = 40;
        onView(TestUtils.withIndex(withId(R.id.recyclerViewIcons),0)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(position,ViewActions.click()));
```

> RecyclerView data size = 66.

Could you explain the reason above code doesn't work?
Thanks and advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an error message saying that the element is not visible at screen and that's because you should first scroll until that element before performing the `click` action.

I use this custom ViewAction in kotlin to perform the scroll:

```
class ScrollToPositionAction(private val position: Int) : ViewAction {
    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return "Scroll RecyclerView to position: $position"
    }

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return allOf<View>(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView::class.java), isDisplayed())
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
        val recyclerView = view as RecyclerView
        recyclerView.layoutManager?.smoothScrollToPosition(
            recyclerView, null, position
        )
        Thread.sleep(500)
        uiController?.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()
    }
}
```

But since you have the `RecyclerViewActions` you could use [scrollToPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions#scrolltoposition) before performing the click:

```
int position = 40;
onView(TestUtils.withIndex(withId(R.id.recyclerViewIcons),0))
    .perform(
        RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(position),
        RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(position, ViewActions.click())
    );
```

Comment: I have recently tried using the RecyclerViewActions first doing scrollToPosition and then actionOnItemAtPosition. It works for any position except for the last one. Have you encountered such an issue?

Comment: Not really, check that you are accessing `size - 1` as it's a zero based index (from 0 to size - 1)

Comment: Yes, I did access the correct position, and it still happens to me.